# GA tracking code not detected on my Amazon s3 hosted site

Tags: amazon-s3, google-analytics

- I have a working static site hosted Amazon s3.
- I've called the primary bucket "www.mysite.com" and have a secondary bucket called "mysite.com" which is being redirected to my primary.
- My "naked" domain is currently being forwarded to: www.mysite.com with a 301 redirect (forward only) via Godaddy (I've tried fwding to s3 endpoint and it doesn't work)
- I've also set up a CName (alias). Host name: "www" pointing to my amazon endpoint "mysite.com.s3-website-is-east-1.amazonaws.com"
- I've added the GA Tag Manager code just after the  tag in all of the pages I want to track and have properly configured a tag in Google Tag Manager.
- I've also waited 24 hours and GA still says my GA code in not installed.

I've searched the web and haven't not come across anything helpful other than this post on stackoverflow http://bit.ly/1nXpRT1.

I have a feeling the issue is with the godaddy and the redirect (the middleman) but I've tried every scenario I can think of and nothing seems to work.

Can it be done?

Mitch

Comment: If your site and redirect are working then the issue is with your google tag manager setup. Are you sure the settings for the google analytics property are configured correctly?

Comment: KingOptimizer - you were correct is was my GTM setup. Thanks. Question, i've set up an event in GTM to track outbound links when a certain btn gets clicked but don't see it in real time GA under events. I have a feeling it's because .js doesn't play nicely with s3 - is there a work around for this?

Comment: Check that you have it correctly firing as its a little different setup than a normal event would be. It should work. Did you check your console and got errors? If you need more help you can contact me here: ppcmasterminds.com